# emacs keybindings in VS Code's Jupyter Notebook

Tags: emacs, visual-studio-code, key-binding

How can I make emacs keybindings work on VS Code while editing a Jupyter Notebook?

I am using the "Emacs Friendly Keymap" extension. It works great while editing normal files (text), but are ignored while editing a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: I have the same symptom .. did you ever find a fix @jmlorenzi

Comment: @mike Last time I checked, this was impossible, i.e. the Jupyter extension completely ignores keybindings on VS Code. So I gave up using the extension...